# NA showing up for no reason

Tags: r, frame, na

I entered

```
 data[data$Ozone>31 & data$Temp>90,]
```

to subset the data frame, but the new frame contains some rows of "NA" which definitely do not exist. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are NA values in a column, it would still show up as NA even if we convert to logical vector.  To avoid that we can also `is.na` also in creating the logical vector for subsetting.

```
data[data$Ozone>31 & !is.na(data$Ozone) & data$Temp>90 & !is.na(data$Temp),]
```

i.e. even if there is a `TRUE` value in one row can be turned to NA if the corresponding element in the other column is NA

```
TRUE & NA
#[1] NA
```

Or if both are NA

```
NA & NA
#[1] NA
```

But, `FALSE` and NA returns FALSE

```
FALSE & NA
#[1] FALSE
```

By using `is.na`, we get the return value of `FALSE` (for the above example)

```
TRUE & !is.na(NA)
#FALSE
```

Returning `NA` will create a new row of NA.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:120), 2*500, replace=TRUE),
   ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("Ozone", "Temp"))))
```